# MongoDB Connection lost while importing data via Laravel, won't restart

Tags: laravel, mongodb, homebrew

I have a local app installation that uses MongodB with Laravel 9 (Along with ElasticSearch and Vue) but they don't really matter for this issue), and my mongo is installed via Homebrew. For the past couple years I was running anMBP with the Intel chip, and I recently upgraded to an M2 MBP. I have installed `mongodb-commnunity` via Homebrew (and the associated `mongodb-database-tools` and `mongosh`). It was initially sort of unstable, but it's been working for a while.

Today, I need to wipe out and restore my data using Laravel's `php artisan migrate` and then dump in the data with a custom command, using the same process we've been using for years. However, partway through the data restoration process, it will die with this error

```
   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException 

  No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling hello on 'localhost:27017']
   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException 

  No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling hello on 'localhost:27017']
```

Looking in `mongo.log` (in `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb`), these are the last few lines:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:06.415-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"collectionUUID":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"b572b2eb-e4de-428e-a1f2-c4fc6b6fd414"}},"namespace":"data.external_file_models","index":"_id_","ident":"index-417-4362401146278060901","collectionIdent":"collection-416-4362401146278060901","commitTimestamp":null}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:07.141-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"data.human_models","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"612ca78d-4bb2-46a9-a16a-ae85957bfc51"}},"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.056-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.056-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileNotOpen: Failed to open interim file /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)38, mongo::AssertionException>\n\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"103501E90","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C61E90","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*)","s+":"A8"},{"a":"103502DF4","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C62DF4","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"30"},{"a":"1034FE6CC","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C5E6CC","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"FC"},{"a":"18691FF48","b":"18690B000","o":"14F48","s":"_ZSt11__terminatePFvvE","C":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"10"},{"a":"18691FEEC","b":"18690B000","o":"14EEC","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"38"},{"a":"100B7BA18","b":"1008A0000","o":"2DBA18","s":"_ZNSt3__1L14__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN5mongo4stdx6threadC1IZNS7_14FTDCController5startEvE3$_0JELi0EEET_DpOT0_EUlvE_EEEEEPvSJ_","C":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, mongo::stdx::thread::thread<mongo::FTDCController::start()::$_0, 0>(mongo::FTDCController::start()::$_0)::'lambda'()>>(void*)","s+":"34"},{"a":"186967FA8","b":"186961000","o":"6FA8","s":"_pthread_start","s+":"94"},{"a":"186962DA0","b":"186961000","o":"1DA0","s":"thread_start","s+":"8"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.6","gitVersion":"26b4851a412cc8b9b4a18cdb6cd0f9f642e06aa7","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Darwin","release":"22.4.0","version":"Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:59:58 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020","machine":"arm64"},"somap":[{"path":"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.6/bin/mongod","machType":2,"b":"1008A0000","vmaddr":"100000000","buildId":"D5C44B3D3C2536E6808192A9AD37F445"},{"path":"/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib","machType":6,"b":"18690B000","vmaddr":"1803A3000","buildId":"FA1E66A848DD3435A00E4FCD9BF5DE69"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib","machType":6,"b":"186961000","vmaddr":"1803F9000","buildId":"B401CFB38DFE32DB92B3BA8AF0F8CA6E"}]}}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"103501E90","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C61E90","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*)","s+":"A8"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"103502DF4","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C62DF4","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"30"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1034FE6CC","b":"1008A0000","o":"2C5E6CC","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"FC"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"18691FF48","b":"18690B000","o":"14F48","s":"_ZSt11__terminatePFvvE","C":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"10"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"18691FEEC","b":"18690B000","o":"14EEC","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"38"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"100B7BA18","b":"1008A0000","o":"2DBA18","s":"_ZNSt3__1L14__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN5mongo4stdx6threadC1IZNS7_14FTDCController5startEvE3$_0JELi0EEET_DpOT0_EUlvE_EEEEEPvSJ_","C":"void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, mongo::stdx::thread::thread<mongo::FTDCController::start()::$_0, 0>(mongo::FTDCController::start()::$_0)::'lambda'()>>(void*)","s+":"34"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"186967FA8","b":"186961000","o":"6FA8","s":"_pthread_start","s+":"94"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:13:08.066-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"186962DA0","b":"186961000","o":"1DA0","s":"thread_start","s+":"8"}}}
```

I've been searching around, I've found references to `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`, and looking in there, I see

```
srwx------   1 root            wheel      0 Jun  8 12:02 mongodb-27017.sock
```

I have tried deleting that file, and whether I do or don't, running `brew services restart mongodb-community` shows a successful restart, but when I attempt to connect with my client (Studio3T), I just get

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Socket error: Connection refused

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
```

and this in `mongo.log` after running `brew services restart mongodb-community`:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.797-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.798-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.821-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.825-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.825-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.825-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.825-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6003,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"GRQFPN62CQ"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.6","gitVersion":"26b4851a412cc8b9b4a18cdb6cd0f9f642e06aa7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.4.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.826-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.827-07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.827-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1126}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T12:52:01.827-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

noting this line

```
Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
```

However, even if I change perms on the sock file to 777, it still won't restart.

So do I just need to change permissions on `/tmp`? Or is there a way to change perms on the sock file when it has been created? I have been careful to not use `sudo` when starting/running any services.

**UPDATE** I completely uninstalled and re-installed everything via Homebrew, and now I can't even get it to start the first time (where it used to be able to connect after restarting my computer).  My logs show this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.458-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.459-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.460-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.461-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1184,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"GRQFPN62CQ"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.6","gitVersion":"26b4851a412cc8b9b4a18cdb6cd0f9f642e06aa7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.4.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1126}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-08T14:01:58.462-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```